# SALE Tags not removed automatically

Tags: sale-price

I am trying to schedule prices for 24-26th on Max Motorsport but a SALE tag appears with no sale price.

Can I remove this tag automatically and enable it on Friday morning but have all sale prices changed as they are scheduled?

Answer (score 0):

If the sale tag is not enabling/disabling automatically, then I think that the sale tag is being managed manually by an attribute.

To manage it automatically, you need to make it dependent on the special price of the product.

To schedule the prices automatically, you can make use of attributes **`special price from`** and **`special price to`** attributes.

[image: product special price]

Please let me know if the logic is clear to you.

Comment: Hi @TejabhagavanKollepara, you can ask a different question since the thing you are asking is not related to this question.